# How can I clean up old notes left in my Gmail account by notes.app?

Tags: gmail, notes.app

I keep my Notes.app notes synced with my Gmail account.

In Gmail, I can see all my current notes in the Notes label and associated sublabels.

I can also see many older versions of current notes, and previously-deleted notes, not attached to any label.

Is there any search I can do in Gmail which will reliably find *all* messages that were created by Notes.app, so that I can delete old versions / "deleted" notes permanently?  (I can find individual notes by searching for their subject line, but I no longer remember all the subject lines of all the notes I've deleted, and I can't find any search string that will reliably find Notes.app notes which no longer have the Notes label.)

Relatedly: is there any way I can configure Notes.app so that when it removes a note (or older version of a note) from the Notes label (or a sublabel) it moves it into the trash, rather than leaving it cluttering up my messages archive?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the following search will find all messages created by Notes.app, and, for me at least, no messages *not* created by it:

```
from:username@gmail.com -in:drafts -in:sent -in:chats -l:SMS
```

(Where `username` is my Gmail username.  The SMS label is used by the [SMS Backup+ android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync&hl=en), which stores SMS messages in Gmail in a similar way to Notes.app, albeit under a different label.)

To find messages which are no longer "live" in Notes.app (i.e., are older versions or deleted notes), and also exclude any other labels like SMS, use "-has:userlabels", like this:

```
from:username@gmail.com -in:drafts -in:sent -in:chats -has:userlabels
```

N.B.: For me the results are 100% old or deleted Notes.app notes, but this search *will* find any other messages created in the same way (i.e., via the IMAP interface, with your address in the from field) so **have a look through the search results carefully before doing any mass deletions**, just to be on the safe side!

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that this search might in some cases catch messages not created by Notes.app, so suggestions of a better search string are very welcome!